# how to provide CSS for particular text in select option?

Tags: javascript, html, css, select, drop-down-menu

I am using bootstrap select-picker for multi line dropdown and have made slight modifications to enable multiple data columns to be binded in single dropdown.

**Now , I want to use different text colour only for data values extracted from database.**

Here is my code

```
 <select name="load" data-toggle="dropdown" class="selectpicker 
show-tick form-control col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" id="cmbID1" data-showContent="true" data-live-search="true" data-live-search-style="startsWith" data-size="10" data-width="350px">
                                <optgroup label="Load details">
                                  <option value="1">No data</option>
                                <asp:Repeater ID="RptLoad" runat= "server">
                                 <ItemTemplate> 
                                  <option value="6" data-divider="true"></option>
                              <option style="white-space:pre-wrap;max-width: 100%;overflow: hidden;word-wrap: normal !important;data-tokens="<%#Eval("Cust_Name")%>" data-content="Customer Name : <%# Eval("Cust_Name")%> <br> Location : <%# Eval("Loc_name") %> <br> Address: <%# Eval("Loc_Address") %> <br> Contact Person : <%# Eval("Loc_ContactP") %> <br> Phone No: <%# Eval("Loc_Phno") %> <br> Email Id : <%# Eval("Loc_Email") %>"><%# Eval("Loc_Id")%>  </option>                            
                             </ItemTemplate>
                              </asp:Repeater>
                                    </optgroup>                                                                                
                         </select>   

                            <script type="text/javascript">                       
                                $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
                             </script>
```

In the above code , I need only the value binded in eval() to be of different colour. for instance:- In the following text "Customer Name : <%# Eval("Cust_Name")%>" , I want *Customer Name header* in black color and *<%# Eval("Cust_Name")%>* in blue colour.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: What have you already tried? Wouldn't wrapping those dynamic statements in tags you can target with normal css selectors be enough?

Answer (score -1):

```
Customer Name : <span style="color:blue"><%# Eval("Cust_Name")%></span>
```